# Не работает MySql 5.6 Open Server

Tags: mysql, openserver

Почему то перестал работать MySql 5.6, когда меняю на другую версию то всё гуд, но у меня все бд то на 5.6. Подскажите что делать?

```
2020-02-26 13:49:50  --------------------------------------------
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Начало процедуры запуска сервера
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Обновление Hosts файла
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Обновление конфигурации MySQL-5.6
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Обновление конфигурации Sendmail
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Обновление конфигурации PHP-7.2
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Обновление конфигурации PHPMyAdmin
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Обновление конфигурации Apache-PHP-7.2
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Запуск MySQL-5.6
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Запуск Apache-PHP-7.2
2020-02-26 13:49:50  Проверка состояния сервера
2020-02-26 13:50:29  Не удалось запустить MySQL-5.6
2020-02-26 13:50:29  Сбой запуска!
2020-02-26 13:50:29  --------------------------------------------
2020-02-26 13:50:29  Начало процедуры остановки сервера
2020-02-26 13:50:29  Остановка системных модулей
2020-02-26 13:50:29  Отключение виртуального диска
2020-02-26 13:50:29  Сервер успешно остановлен за 0,468 секунд!


2020-02-26 13:49:50 0 [Note] c:\ospanel\modules\database\MySQL-5.6\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 5.6.41-log) starting as process 9836 ...
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1321246107 and 1321246107 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1321246117 in the ib_logfiles!
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2020-02-26 13:49:50 9836 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 0. Cannot continue operation
```

Comment: попробуйте поменять конфигурацию PHP, Apache-PHP

Comment: @humster_spb К сожалению это не помогло

Comment: сам openserver тут не при делах. вам MySQL в лог пишет, что работа была завершена не корректно, и crash recovery у него не получается. вот этом направлении и ищите ответы.

Comment: у текущего пользователя есть права на чтение файлов? ничего в этом не менялось?

Comment: @teran Оказалось что я выключил компьютер когда работал ОС, пришлось удалить бд которая была открыта в этот момент, потому что в ней произошел сбой. Мне проще было пересоздать одну бд чем разбираться в этом несколько часов.